# The Dirac function derivative potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

Does the Dirac delta function derivative potential have a solution in one dimension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpret the derivative of the Dirac delta potential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161275/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201347/2451