# Proof of Gauss' Law

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

How would you prove Gauss' law for an asymmetrical closed surface? I can find it for symmetrical surface but couldn't for Asymmetrical surfaces.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38404/2451 and links therein.

Comment: To clarify, I presume you're asking how to derive it from Coulomb's Law?