# How to prove Gauss's law div(E) = rho/epsilon from Coulomb's law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law, coulombs-law

As we know from coulomb's law that:
$$\vec{E} = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon R^2} \hat{R}$$

using the above equation, how can I verify that:
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E}=\frac{q}{\epsilon}$$

I have tried to do it a home, but couldn't figure it out. Explicitly showing all steps would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38404/2451 and links therein.