# Magnetic field generated by magnetic monopole?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

My goal is to show that a magnetic field generated by a magnetic monopole is $$-\frac{1}{2r^2}\hat{r}$$ but I'm having a little trouble doing so. I know that $$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{B} = 4\pi \rho_M  $$ where $\rho_M$ is the density of "magnetic charge". How do I go about deriving what the magnetic monopole field is? Furthermore, what is the value of $\rho_M$ here?

Comment: Do you know how to do the same problem for an electric charge?

Comment: Yes I do. What differences would there be between a magnetic monopole field and say, an electric field from a point charge?

Comment: None!$\hspace{0mm}$

Comment: This is mostly a duplicate of [Are the Maxwell's equations enough to derive the law of Coulomb?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44418/are-the-maxwells-equations-enough-to-derive-the-law-of-coulomb/) and [Deriving Coulomb's Law from Gauss's Law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/299719/deriving-coulombs-law-from-gausss-law/) - the different setting makes them look different, but at heart they are identical.

Answer (score 1):

$$\newcommand{\V}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} \rho_M(\V{r}) = e_M \delta(\V{r}) $$ where $e_M$ would be the charge of the monopole. The method is then exactly the same as for a point electric charge:

1. use the integral form of the law $\V{\nabla}.\V{B}=4\pi\rho_M$, i.e. that

$$\iint_{S_r} \V{B}\ .\V{dS} = e_M$$

where $S_r$ is the sphere of radius $r$ centred on the origin.

2. use the symmetry of the sources to argue that $\V{B}$ is radial and depends only on the radius $r$.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from the definition of a point magnetic dipole, which is a point that generates the magnetic field of a closed circular current at the limit r->0. In this limit, the dipole moment of the current must stay the same no matter the radius.

Next, consider that a magnetic monopole would violate Gauss's law for magnetism. The flux through a closed surface of the magnetic field generated by internal currents would stop being zero, and the divergence of the magnetic field would also stop being zero.