# Derivation of Gauß' Law

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, coulombs-law

I am reading a book about special relativity and the author derives Gauss law the following way:
$$\int_{S_R}E\dot{}d\textbf{S}=\frac{q}{4\pi R^2\epsilon_0}\int_{S_R}dS=\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$$ (where $S_R$ is the surface of a sphere with radius $R$) from the fact that $$\textbf{E}=\frac{q\textbf{r}}{4\pi \epsilon_0||\textbf{r}||^3} .$$ I don't understand how he arrives at the last term, could somebody explain this to me?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which book? Which page?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38404/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The surface of a sphere is $4\pi R^2$

Comment: @caverac Thanks, I already figured it out. What a dumb question haha.

Comment: @Qmechanic "Special Relativity" by Nicholas Woodhouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the form stated, the magnitude of the field $\mathbf{E}$ is constant and the direction is radial, i.e. it is a vector normal to the sphere.

Recall that $d\mathbf{S}$ is a vector whose magnitud is the area of the surface and points outwards. Therefor $\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=EdS$ (where the scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is performed as usual, taking in account that $\mathbf{E}$ and $d\mathbf{S}$ are paralel). Consider now a sphere whith origin in the center. It is clear that, since $E$ depends solely in $r$, must be constant along the surface, so it can be factored out the integral.

Since $\int_{S_R}d\mathbf{S}$ is the area of the sphere,  the integral is $4\pi R^2$. Puting all together you recover $\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out (that was a really dumb question):
$\int_{S_R}{d\textbf{S}\dot{}\textbf{E}}$ is the same as $\int_{S_R}dS \ \textbf{E}\dot{}\textbf{n}$ (where $\textbf{n}$ is the unit vector pointing away from the sphere). Because $\textbf{n}=\frac{\textbf{r}}{||\textbf{r}||}$ the dot product becomes $\frac{q}{4\pi R^4\epsilon_0}\textbf{r}\dot{}{\textbf r}$ and $\textbf {r} \dot{} \textbf {r}=R^2$. The Integral $\int_{S_R}dS$ is equal to the surface area of a sphere, so the integral becomes $\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$.