# How to prove Gauss law geometrically (without coordinates) from Coulomb's law?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, coulombs-law

Namely that the Flux of the electric field through any surface equals the charge enclosed/vacuum permittivity.

Without any coordinates or reference to axis.

Comment: What are you trying to prove it from?  What equations are on the table?

Comment: So we're starting from Maxwell's equations as a given?

Comment: No I don't think so. First one is basically gauss law.

Comment: Then what is your starting point? What do you want to prove it from?

Comment: Coulombs law...

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38404/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with Maxwell's equation you can apply the divergence theorem.

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$\int_V(\nabla \cdot \vec{E})dV = \frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int_V \rho dV$$
$$\oint_A \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{A} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$$

Where $\oint_A \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{A}$ is the electric flux.

Comment: No that's trivial.thats not a proof of the law it's just equating different forms of stating it.

Comment: This is a proof if you start with Maxwell's equations and the divergence theorem being given. What is your starting point then? Also, are you just downvoting answers you don't like, even if they aren't wrong?

Comment: Check my inswer how I would prove this. Yours is not the proof as I said. Using my answer, ( I found it in a textbook) you can prove divergence theorem which is equivalent to gauss law. Starting with divergence theorem to prove gauss law is circular.

Comment: I guess I don't understand. How is the divergence theorem equivalent to Gauss' law? It seems like Gauss' integral law is a consequence of the divergence theorem, which is something you prove in Real Analysis class

Comment: To calculate divergence you need to calculate the Flux though the boundary of small volume  first than divide by the volume.

Comment: In terms of differential forms and using Lorentz-Heaviside units: $$
Q \equiv \int_U\star\rho \underset{\text{Maxwell}}{=} \int_U d\star E \underset{\text{Stokes}}{=}\int_{\partial U} \star E \equiv \Phi
$$

Answer (score 0):

physic is proved by experiments, so enclose a charge in some surface and measure the flux, it is easier taking a conducting surface and measure the charge of the surface. this and of measurements finally came to create the Maxwell equations. and sometimes laws are explained by them. So you should say from what standpoint you want to proof  the law.

Answer (score 0):

This I think answers it. The point is just to show that the Flux through any surface is equal to the Flux through a sphere  because any surface patch will always be (R/r) ^2 /cos¶ bigger that the corresponding sphere patch but it will be tilted by an angle ¶ reducing the Flux by cos¶. Since the electric field also drops as distance squared everything cancels out and you just get the electric field times the area of the sphere.

Comment: ie $\oint \hat r\cdot d\vec A / r^2 = 4\pi$