# Derivation of Gauss' Law of Gravitation

Tags: newtonian-gravity, gauss-law, calculus

this question is simple, I was looking for a good derivation to [Gauss' Law of gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity) $$\int \vec g.d\vec A=-4\pi GM $$ but was unable to find a good enough one online. Hence may I know its derivation?

Comment: Its identical to the Electrostatic derivation, if you swap $ 1/4  \pi \epsilon_0 $ for G, and take into account that positive mass is analogous to negative charge when it comes to the direction of the force.

Comment: @JohnyO42 i will check out the electrostatic derivation, thank you!

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38404/2451