# Differentiation and delta function

Tags: mathematical-physics, differentiation, dirac-delta-distributions

Need help doing this simple differentiation.
Consider 4 d Euclidean(or Minkowskian) spacetime.
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mu}\frac{(a-x)_\mu}{(a-x)^4}= ?
\end{equation}
where $a_\mu$ is a constant vector and the indices are summed over since one really doesn't need to bother about upper and lower indices in flat space.
Also $(a-x)^2=(a-x)_\mu(a-x)_\mu$. A simple minded calculation gives me the result $0$. But I think the answer may contain Dirac Delta function like the relation below in 3 dimension
\begin{equation}
{\bf{\nabla}} . \frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}=4\pi \delta ^3(r)
\end{equation}
A corollary question. What will be $\partial_{\mu}\frac{1}{(a-x)^2}$ ? Is it
$\frac{2(a-x)_\mu}{(a-x)^4}$ or does it also involve the Delta function?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9255/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In a $d$-dimensional Euclidean space (with positive definite norm), one has 
   $$\tag{1} \vec{\nabla} \cdot \frac{\vec{r}}{r^d}
   ~=~{\rm Vol}(S^{d-1})~\delta^d(\vec{r}), $$
   cf. the [divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) and arguments involving either test functions and integration by parts, or $\epsilon$-regularization, similar to methods applied in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/9284/2451). In eq. (1) the ${\rm Vol}(S^{d-1})$ is the surface area of the $(d-1)$-dimensional units [sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) $S^{d-1}$.
2. By similar arguments one may show that the identity
   $$\tag{2}   \vec{\nabla}(r^{2-d}) ~=~(2-d)\frac{\vec{r}}{r^d} , \qquad d\neq 2, $$
   contains no distributional contributions in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space.
3. For the related questions in Minkowski space, one suggestion is to introduce an $\epsilon$-regularization in the Euclidean formulation, and then perform a [Wick rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation), and at the end of the calculation, let $\epsilon\to 0^+$.

Comment: Thanks Qmechanic. Writing down your equation in the index notation gives
\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu \frac{x_\mu}{x^2}=2\pi^2\delta^4(x)
\end{equation}
in 4d which is the result I wanted. Now it looks a bit silly to have asked the question in the first place.