# Dirac delta function equation intuition and proof

Tags: mathematics, gauss-law, dirac-delta-distributions

What is the intuition and where should I find proof of this equation (do not know what its name is). It is used to derive Gauss law from Newton equation.
$${\nabla \cdot \Bigg ( \frac{\vec{s}}{|\vec{s}|^3}\Bigg)=4\pi \delta^3 (\vec{s})}$$

Comment: See [this](http://www.physicspages.com/2011/11/14/dirac-delta-function-in-three-dimensions/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75557/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9255/2451 and links therein.