# How to derive the $\frac{4\pi}{3}\vec{p}\delta^3(\vec{r})$ element for the dipole field, from its potential?

Tags: electrostatics, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta-distributions, dipole, dipole-moment

This might be a bit more general question about how to figure out what is the appropriate (delta) expression in singular points, but e.g. for the dipole, we can derive its potential by a taylor approiximation: 
$$\Phi(\vec{r})=\frac{\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r}}{r^3}.\tag{1}$$

However, this was derived from $$\int d^3r' \rho(\vec{r'})-\vec{r'}\nabla\frac{1}{r},\tag{2}$$ for which the above potential expression is valid only for $r\neq 0$.
However, the field is said to be derived from the above potential (which seems to be true only for $r\neq 0$), and it is

$$\vec{E}(\vec{r})=\frac{3\hat{r}(\hat{r}\cdot\vec{p})-\vec{p}}{r^3}-\frac{4\pi}{3}\vec{p}\delta^3(\vec{r}).\tag{3}$$

The first term can be derived by calculating $$\vec{E}=-\nabla\Phi\tag{4}$$ when assuming $r\neq 0$, but for the second element it's unclear how to derive it.

As this basically a result of $\Delta \frac{1}{r}$ I can see why $4\pi\delta(\vec{r})$ is involved, but how does one derive this exact term? and why how come the field is a sum of a delta function at 0, and a function the isn't defined/converges at 0?

Comment: Similar Math.SE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3081591/11127

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Formally one should introduce testfunctions to deal with [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29). Another more physical approach is to regularize the dipole potential (1)
$$ \Phi_{\varepsilon}~=~ \frac{\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r}}{(r^2+\varepsilon)^{3/2}}, \tag{A} $$
similar to my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/9284/2451). The regularized dipole potential $\Phi_{\varepsilon}\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is infinitely many times differentiable. The regularized electric field then becomes:
$$ \vec{E}_{\varepsilon}~=~-\vec{\nabla}\Phi_{\varepsilon}
~=~\frac{3(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r})\vec{r}-r^2\vec{p} }{(r^2+\varepsilon)^{5/2}} - \vec{p}\frac{\varepsilon}{(r^2+\varepsilon)^{5/2}}. \tag{B}$$
To derive OP's sought-for eq. (3) it is straightforward to check that the last term in eq. (B) is a regularized [3D Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function)
$$ \frac{\varepsilon}{(r^2+\varepsilon)^{5/2}}~\to~ \frac{4\pi}{3}\delta^3(\vec{r}) \quad\text{for}\quad\varepsilon\to 0^+. \tag{C}$$